# How to write a math notation for a set generated by a relation?

Tags: functions, notation, relations

I am trying to write a mathematical notation for a set of variables and their values over time.

A function **$f$** should map each of **$N$** variables to a value of **$0$ or $1$** over time and the results are stored in a set **$S$** in an accumulative manner.

For example:

- $N = 3$
- variables: $a, b, c ∈ [0, 5]$
- time($t$): $0...3$

```
 time      f(a),f(b),f(c)              S
======    ===============      ===================
  0            0,0,0           {(a,0),(b,0),(c,0)}
  1            0,1,0           {(a,0),(b,1),(c,0)}
  2            1,0,0           {(a,1),(b,1),(c,0)}
  3            1,0,1           {(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)}
```

How can I write a mathematical notation for set **$S$**?

Comment: Is there a reason your set $S$ does seem to accumulate anything? It just changes over time according to $S_t = \{ (a,f_t(a)), (b,f_t(b)), (c,f_t(c)) \}$.

Comment: @LinAlg This is close to what I am looking for. How would you write a notation for **S** for **N** variables and their output by function **f** at time **t**.

Comment: Let $T$ be the set of $N$ variables, then you get $S_t = \{ (v, f_t(v)) : v \in N\}$

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could use state notation as I proposed at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271725/is-there-a-shorthand-notation-for-adding-an-element-to-a-set/3594755#3594755) question, where your state = time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of your example is as a sequence of functions
$f_1, f_2, \ldots$ each of which maps $N$ to $\{0,1\}$. Then when you think of a function as a set of ordered pairs, the sets you want are just the functions themselves.

Thinking of a function as a set of ordered pairs is usually a formality that stays in the background in most applications. Here it is exactly what you want. Perhaps you can just say that at the start of your document.

In your example, the value of $f$ changes from $0$ to $1$ at just one point at each (time) step. The inverse image of $1$ increases by $1$ at each step, reflecting the sense in which something is "growing".

If you are always going to have $|N|$ steps then your sequence of functions is easily encoded as a permutation of $N$, indicating the order in which its elements are "added".

Comment: Yes, you are correct. the output of function **f** is being added to a set **S**, but there is only one function on **N** variables. The relation of function **f** as an ordered pair from the input space to output which constructs the set **S** over time is exactly what I am looking for. Something like: `S={s ∈ {0,1} | f: ([0,5])^N --> ({0,1})^N}`. I don't know how to write the math notation.

Comment: The semantic content of what you describe is completely described by a single function $A$ from $N$ to $\{1, 2, \ldots, |N|\}$ such that $A(x)$ is the time step at which you add $x$. Or use the inverse of that function, if you prefer. I think you are overthinking "say this mathematically".